# PHP Contact form does not send

Tags: php, email-attachments, contact-form

Quick question I'm a front end developer and php isn't my strongest point :) I built this contact form. The problem is php does not seem to be sending the email. Could you help me spot the problem? I'm out of ideas here...

Here is the form:

```
            <form id="job-app" method="post" action="careersss.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="container">
                    <label for="name"> Full Name:
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <label for="email"> Email:
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <label for="number"> Contact Number:
                        <input type="text" name="number" id="number">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <label for="resume"> Resume (CV): <span> File types allowed: Word Document or PDF</span>
                        <input type="file" name="resume" id="resume">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <label for="cover"> Cover Letter:
                        <textarea name="cover" id="cover"></textarea>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="container human">
                    <label for="human"> Are you human? What is the sum of:
                        <input type="text" name="human" id="human">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Send</button>
            </form>
```

Here is PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){

    if(!empty($_FILES['resume']['name'])){

        $file_name = $_FILES['resume']['name'];
        $temp_name = $_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'];
        $file_type = $_FILES['resume']['type'];

        // Get extension of the file
        $base = basename($file_name);
        $extension = substr($base, strlen($base)-4, strlen($base));

        // Only allow these file types
        $allowed_extensions = array('.doc', 'docx', '.pdf');

        // Check that this file type is allowed
        if(in_array($extension, $allowed_extensions)){

            // Mail essentials store all variables from

            $from = $_POST['email'];
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $number = $_POST['number'];
            $to = 't.slegaitis@gmail.com';
            $subject = 'Job Application ' . date('Y/m/d');
            $message = $_POST['cover'];

            // Things needed
            $file = $temp_name;
            $content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)));
            $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

            // Mail Headers
            $header = 'From: '.$from.'\r\n';
            $header .= 'Reply-To: '.$from.'\r\n';
            $header .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n';

            // Declaring that this email have multiple kinds (i.e Plain text and attachment)
            $header .= 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\''.$uid.'\'\r\n\r\n';
            $header .= 'This is a multi-part message in MIME Format. \r\n';


            // Plain text Part
            $header .= '--'.$uid.'\r\n';
            $header .= 'Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n';
            $header .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n';
            $header .= 'Name: '.$name.'\r\n';
            $header .= 'Contact Number: '.$number.'\r\n';
            $header .= 'Email Address: '.$from.'\r\n';
            $header .= $message.'\r\n';

            // File attachment
            $header .= '--'.$uid.'\r\n';
            $header .= "Content-Type: ".$file_type."; name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
            $header .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n';
            $header .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\''.$file_name.'\'\r\n';

            // Send the mail

            if(mail($to, $subject, '', $header)){
                echo('success');
            } else {
                echo('fail');
            }



        } else {

            echo('file type not allowed');
        }


    } else {

        echo('No file posted');
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Check the error logs and add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag:  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` It is possible that your mail server is not even running.

Comment: Nothing happens is I click send. Only it seems to check whether the file is attached or not and whether its correct file type.

Comment: `if(mail($to, $subject, '', $header)){` - 3rd parameter should be `$message`

Comment: Right $replyto variable was a typo should have been $to. Fixed yet same, nothing happens :(

Comment: @Fred-ii- But the message is in the $header. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: It could be either/or. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything, just as Jay said.

Comment: No errors. Displays success

Comment: First of all if you are trying to send an email from your local system. it will not send. it required server. I got following error in your code:-Notice: Undefined variable: "replyto" in careersss.php on line 36. please check that  it will be properly defined and assigned through a value. rest of it the code seems fine at my end. put it on some server end it will work.

Comment: I have I moved the page to the server where the site is hosted.

Comment: will you remove this one also Notice: Undefined variable: "replyto" in careersss.php